# PXSelector for workgroup

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to create an entry field to lookup into the workgroups.  I have a custom table and I am trying to define the workgroup that is responsible for it.  I assumed the PXCompanyTreeSelector would provide the lookup.  Is there an attribute I am missing or does the lookup need to be defined separately.

```
    public abstract class responsibleGroup : IBqlField { }
    [PXDBInt]
    [PXDefault(typeof(EDPartnerInfo.responsibleGroup), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.NullOrBlank)]
    [PX.TM.PXCompanyTreeSelector]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Responsible Group", Enabled = false)]
    public virtual int? ResponsibleGroup { get; set; }
    #endregion
```

The form formats it as a selector, but the screen only shows a read-only field on execution.

```
<px:PXSelector ID="edResponsibleGroup" runat="server" DataField="ResponsibleGroup">
</px:PXSelector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set this field to be disabled in this line:

```
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Responsible Group", Enabled = false)]
```

You need to remove `Enabled = false` from `PXUIFieldAttribute`.

Comment: Victim of the old Copy & Paste!